# How to insert a new data inside an object in dart

Tags: json, dictionary, object, dart

I am trying to update data inside an object, here is the sample of object:

```
List myData = [
               {"data": "hello 1", "data 2": "hello 2"}
             ];
```

is it possible to add `"data 3":"hello 3"` inside `myData[0]` without creating a new object? so here is the the object that I want:

```
List myData = [
          {"data": "hello 1", "data 2": "hello 2","data 3":"hello 3"}
   ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add data to the map:

```
myData[0]["data 3"] = "hello 3";
```